# How to check if the swf has been unfocused in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, click, focus, flash

I just thought it would be useful to know how to check if an swf has been focused or otherwise. This situation arises when the end user clicks outside of the stage (on the address bar of the browser, for example).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, notFocused);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, focused);
function notFocused(e:Event) {
    trace("Not focused");
}
function focused(e:Event) {
    trace("Focused");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also avail NativeApplication for the same in AIR application.

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.events.Event;

NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, onActivate);
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, onDeactivate);

function onActivate(e:Event){
        trace("Activate");
}

function onDeactivate(e:Event){
    trace("Deactivate");
}
```