# detect when the client focus leave the window

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i saw some online flash games can do this:

when you switch your current web to other windows or other web tabs, the application program will draw a  black block and tell you've leave the application, click on the flash area to resume .

i've tried some event like focus in and out or mouse leave on the stage,but the reaction isn't what i expected.maybe i use them in the wrong way .please tell me if you got the solution.

```
var count:int = 0;

this.stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE,function(e:Event):void
{
    //only be called if your mouse cursor leave the area,but can't detect whether you're actually switch to other program.
    trace('mouseleave',count++);
});

this.stage.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT,function(e:Event):void
{
    //no reaction
    trace('focus out',count++);
});

this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,function(e:Event):void
{
    //no reaction
    trace('mouseenter',count++);
});
```

Comment: It is already answered in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373100/how-to-check-if-the-swf-has-been-unfocused-in-as3). Search before post a question

Comment: maybe you should try it. it doesn't work until you click on it,which means if you download it but never  click on it,the activate/deactivate things will never work.

Comment: I don't know why it is not dispatching when selecting other tabs of the browser(before clicks on the stage). Besides, it is working good in swf and when you minimize and maximize the browser. I guess there(html/javascript) must be workaround to fix this. Also need to focus on `<object>` tag of html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods:

- Use `Event.ACTIVATE` event. But a swf should be on focus before.
- Use JavaScript call from ActionScript to check is a window or a tab on focus.