# How to make sure flash version of player paused when web page lose focus?

Tags: javascript, flash

I built a page to play HLS content on most platform, use HTML5 video + HLS.js by default and fallback to flash version of player(Grind Player) if MSE is not supported.

I'm trying to stop video tag from playing when user switch to another tab or another program. After reading some answers of similar questions, I used code below:

```
function PauseVideo() {
    if (isFlashPlayerUsed) {
        var isPlaying = player.getPlaying();
        AddLog("player.playing: " + isPlaying);

        if (isPlaying)
            player.pause();
    }
    else {
        AddLog("player.paused: " + player.paused);

        if (!player.paused)
            player.pause();
    }
}

$(window).on("blur", function (e) {
    AddLog("window.blur fired.");
    PauseVideo();
});

$(window).on("focusout", function (e) {
    AddLog("window.focusout fired.");
    PauseVideo();
});

$(document).on("visibilityChange", function (e) {
    AddLog("document.visibilityChange fired.");

    if (document.visibilityState == "hidden")
        PauseVideo();
});
```

However, I found that in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7, Flash version of Player is used, and window.blur fired if I clicked anything other than player itself even if it's in the same page, but didn't fire if player is on focus and I clicked another program.

How to make sure the video will always pause when the window or tab lose focus, even if flash version of player is used?

Comment: The detection code must exist inside the Flash app itself. It will be [AS3 code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12373101/2057709), not JavaScript. The `.swf` file is the compiled Flash app (eg: video player). If it's very important / neccessary to you, then you'll just have to download the [AS3/Flex SDK](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html) (has AS3 compiler) and learn some Actionscript code. The [External Interface API](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb2.html) might help you pass "pause" instruction when JS or IE detect changes..

Comment: PS: By saying _"learn some Actionscript code"_ I mean understand the source code of your mentioned _"video player"_ (there should be a main `.as` file somewhere to edit & re-compile)